# Error al iniciar proyecto de Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Tengo el siguiente error cuando ejecuto mi aplicación gradle de Spring Boot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi clase main:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola creo que debes especificar la clase principal lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera si usas maven:

```
<properties>
    <start-class>com.example.MsSimulatorLeasingApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

o

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
        <configuration>    
            <mainClass>com.example.MsSimulatorLeasingApplication</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Para poder ayudarte de forma mas especifica por favor puedes alcanzar mayor información como la estructura de tu proyecto, versiones de Spring, de Java, etc.

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!